# set custom backgound for android app on the fly

Tags: android

I am planning to develop an android app in which the customer will be able to change the app background and set his personal images or photos as background. But this means the images will not be there in "drawables", I am very new to android, I have been searching very long for this, Could any one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
    public class GalleryAdapter extends Activity {
        private int count;
        private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
        private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
        private String[] arrPath;
        private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.image_selector);
            final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
            final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
            Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,null,orderBy);
            int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
            this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
            this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count];
            this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
            this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];

            for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
                imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
                int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
                int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
                arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
            }

            GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
            imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
            imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
            imagecursor.close();
            final Button selectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectBtn);
            selectBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
                    int cnt = 0;
                    String selectImages = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
                        if (thumbnailsselection[i]) {
                            cnt++;
                            selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i] + "|";
                        }
                    }

                    if (cnt == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select at least one image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You've selected Total " + cnt + " image(s).",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("SelectedImages", selectImages);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private LayoutInflater mInflater;
            public ImageAdapter() {
                mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }

            public int getCount() {
                return count;
            }
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ViewHolder holder;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item,null);
                    holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
                    holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);

                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }
                holder.checkbox.setId(position);
                holder.imageview.setId(position);
                holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                        int id = cb.getId();
                        if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                            cb.setChecked(false);
                            thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                        } else {
                            cb.setChecked(true);
                            thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                        }
                    }
                });
                holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int id = v.getId();
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + arrPath[id]),"image/*");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnails[position]);
                holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
                holder.id = position;
                return convertView;
            }
        }
        class ViewHolder {
            ImageView imageview;
            CheckBox checkbox;
            int id;
        }

}
```

image_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button android:id="@+id/selectBtn" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Select"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:minWidth="200px" />
    <GridView android:id="@+id/PhoneImageGrid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit" 
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp" 
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_above="@id/selectBtn" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

gallery_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/thumbImage" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/itemCheckBox" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. I have a "change background button on clicking it i should be able to browse for  images.

Comment: check now,i changed the answer..!

Comment: sorry to bug you, but iam new to this i think a few packages are missing, say holder

Comment: These are the errors i get 
----------
motivation_image_selector cannot be resolved or is not a field.
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments 
Duplicate method getView(int, View, ViewGroup) in type ImagechangeActivity.ImageAdapter
----------
Please help thanks in advance

Comment: have you created image_selector.xml ?

Comment: R.layout.gallery_item
R.layout.image_selector
itemCheckBox
Could you please tel what they are . i am getting error:( Sorry again

Comment: Thank you very much noby, :) i have got two mor errors
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type ------------View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})
-----------
Could you please have a look i can find out why is this erro

Comment: which version API are you using..? Its better to go for 2.1 i.e, API level 7

Comment: hi am using 2.2...level 8,,,,,,,,,,the eclipse i use dont have 2.1, it has 2.31, 1.6

Comment: Can you please tell me on which line you are getting this error. Share your log cat content..

Comment: image_selector is there a xml file like that? thanks in advance

Comment: ya.. its an separate xml file have you created it or not..?

Comment: I have fixed all the errors. Thanx for your kind help. One more thing, while running the application it's showing "the application has stopped unexpectedly". Could u please help me on this. I am helpless. :(

Comment: At that time see the log cat it will describe what was the cause for crashing of the application.

Comment: 11-14 20:06:26.673: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(507):     ... 11 more
11-14 20:06:26.704: WARN/ActivityManager(58):   Force finishing activity image.test.one/.ImageoneActivity
11-14 20:06:27.250: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{44fec178 image.test.one/.ImageoneActivity}
11-14 20:06:34.573: DEBUG/dalvikvm(203): GC_EXPLICIT freed 39 objects / 1272 bytes in 906ms
11-14 20:06:38.613: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{44fec178 image.test.one/.ImageoneActivity}

Comment: Ok, the problem is with your image file. Use some small image which will be small in size and resolution (bitmap), then try it. If it offers to wait, then select wait and see...